# Latex error: \begin{thebibliography} on input line 1 ended by \end{bibitemlist}. \end{thebibliography}

Tags: bibliographies, memoir, bibliographystyle

I am trying to compile my thesis using a `memoir` class template. When I import the chapters the file compiles fine but when I type the code for the bibliography in the backmatter section (`\bibliographystyle{chicago} \bibliography{bibliography}`) I get the following errors in the `.bbl` file and the file doesn't compile:

> ```
> error: \begin{thebibliography} on input line 1 ended by \end{bibitemlist}. \end{thebibliography}
>
> error: \begin{document} ended by \end{thebibliography}. \end{thebibliography}
>
> error: Extra \endgroup. \end{thebibliography}
> ```

The problem is that when I use the same `.bib` file and commands in a document class for the individual chapters, the bibliography is generated without any issues, but it doesn't work on my thesis memoir class project. I'm using TeXstudio, and my bib file is autogenerated by Mendeley if this matters.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I did my best to reproduce the error with as little code as possible. I hope this makes things clearer:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openbib]{memoir} 

\usepackage{datetime}

\frenchspacing

\OnehalfSpacing

\setsecnumdepth{subsection}

\maxsecnumdepth{subsubsection}

\usepackage{calc,soul}
\makeatletter 
\newlength\dlf@normtxtw 
\setlength\dlf@normtxtw{\textwidth} 
\newsavebox{\feline@chapter} 
\newcommand\feline@chapter@marker[1][4cm]{%
    \sbox\feline@chapter{% 
        \resizebox{!}{#1}{\fboxsep=1pt%
            \colorbox{gray}{\color{white}\thechapter}% 
    }}%
    \rotatebox{90}{% 
        \resizebox{%
            \heightof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}+\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}}% 
        {!}{\scshape\so\@chapapp}}\quad%
    \raisebox{\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}}{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}%
} 
\newcommand\feline@chm[1][4cm]{%
    \sbox\feline@chapter{\feline@chapter@marker[#1]}% 
    \makebox[0pt][c]{% aka \rlap
        \makebox[1cm][r]{\usebox\feline@chapter}%
}}


\newcommand{\clearemptydoublepage}{\newpage{\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}}

\makeindex


\usepackage{import}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{slashed}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{chicago}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,positioning,shadows,shapes}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\widowpenalty=1000
\clubpenalty=1000




\begin{document}
    

    \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
    \maxtocdepth{subsection}
    \tableofcontents*
    
    \clearemptydoublepage
    
    \listoffigures
    \clearemptydoublepage
    
    
    \mainmatter
    
    
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    
    \clearemptydoublepage
    
    Lorem ipsum \nocite{vanFraassen1980}
    
    
    \backmatter
    
    
    \bibliographystyle{chicago}
    \bibliography{test}
    

    
    \clearemptydoublepage
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: It would help *a lot* if you could show us a small example document that reproduces the error with as little code as possible. I just tried the small example document at https://gist.github.com/moewew/b052d91c742d370f2ae1975ce230c291 and things worked fine.

Comment: You are right but I am not sure how I can regenerate the problem with minimum code. The thing is that the problem only appears when I put in the \bibliography command. When I don't everything works perfectly.

Comment: There must be some code in your document that makes the bibliography fail. Most likely it is code in your preamble. My example shows that there are preambles where `chicago` works, so you 'just' have to find the bit in your preamble that causes the error. There are many pages like https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 that explain how to best generate an example document.

Answer (score 2):

The problem can be reproduced in the following MWE

```
\documentclass[british]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{chicago}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{elk,
  author    = {Anne Elk},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1972},
  publisher = {Monthy \& Co.},
  location  = {London},
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
Lorem \cite{elk,article-full}

\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{\jobname,xampl}
\end{document}
```

Both the `memoir` class and the `chicago` package change the definition of the `thebibliography` environment. Unfortunately, `chicago` does that in a way that sort of ignores that `thebibliography` is an environment: It only changes the begin code, not the end code of the environment. Assuming the usual definition of `thebibliography` this is not a big deal, but with `memoir`'s additional changes, things go wrong.

I suggest the following workaround that restores `memoir`'s redefinition after loading `chicago`, but applies the required tweaks to the bibliography formatting.

```
\documentclass[british]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{chicago}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{%
  \bibsection
  \begin{bibitemlist}{#1}}{\end{bibitemlist}\postbibhook}

\renewenvironment{bibitemlist}[1]{%
  \typeout{bibitemlist}
  \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
       {\leftmargin\z@
        \advance\leftmargin\bibindent
        \itemindent -\bibindent
        \listparindent \itemindent
        \parsep \z@
        \@openbib@code
        \usecounter{enumiv}%
        \let\p@enumiv\@empty
        \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}%
        \biblistextra}%
  \sloppy
  \clubpenalty4000
  \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
  \widowpenalty4000%
  \sfcode`\.\@m}%
  {\def\@noitemerr
    {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
    \endlist}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{elk,
  author    = {Anne Elk},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1972},
  publisher = {Monthy \& Co.},
  location  = {London},
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
Lorem \cite{elk,article-full}

\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{\jobname,xampl}
\end{document}
```

[image: Nicely formatted bibliography.]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I 've implemented your code and the errors dissolved, but the problem now is that my bibliography appears only in one specific style -- which I'm not sure what it is it but it's not chicago -- and the style doesn't change no matter what \bibliography style I choose.

Comment: @Floyd That is odd. Are you sure there are no other errors that block proper bibliography generation. You may have to pass the option `oldfontcommands` to `memoir` to get `chicago` to work properly.

Comment: I should add that I don't actually know if `chicago` can give you Chicago style as currently defined by the CMoS. If you need that you may have to look into `biblatex-chicago` or `windycity`.

Comment: It is odd indeed. `oldfontcommands` doesn't help either. But thanks for your help anyway -- much appreciated.